# Flutter GetX trigger function when state changes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

How can I call a specific function in my stateless widget, whenever my GetX state changes?
E.g. whenever the index of my bottomnavigationbar changes, how can I trigger an event?

```
    Obx(
        () =>
           BottomNavigationBar(
               items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                   icon: Icon(Icons.explore),
                   label: 'Erkunden',
                  ),           
               ],
               currentIndex: bottomNavigationController.index.value,
               onTap: (index) {
                     bottomNavigationController.changeIndex(index);
               },
            )
     ),
```

**EDIT:**

```
 class BottomNavigationController extends GetxController {
     RxInt index = 0.obs;

     void changeIndex(int val) {
          index.value = val;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get your controller, listen changes in a method according to your requirements. It may be in constructor, build method, or a button's onPress method etc.

```
BottomNavigationController bnc = Get.find();

bnc.index.listen((val) {
  // Call a function according to value
});
```

Comment: Where do I put this listener?

Comment: You can put it in costructor, build method etc.

Comment: You can put in controller `onReady` or `onInit` methods

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @ertgrull's answer:

You can add a listener to any stream, but Getx also has built in [worker functions](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md#workers) for this type of functionality.

Usually when I need this I add the listener in the `onInit` of the controller.

```
class BottomNavigationController extends GetxController {
  RxInt index = 0.obs;

  void changeIndex(int val) {
    index.value = val;
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    ever(index, (value) {
  // call your function here
  // any code in here will be called any time index changes
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I heard about the workers, but my functions I want to call are not inside my GetxController, but inside my class/widget with the build method.

Comment: Ok well you can do as @ertgrull suggested and put the standard listener syntax, or `ever` function in the constructor or build method. What function are you trying to call? What are you trying to do? Because unless you're actually displaying the index or need a rebuild of your bottom nav bar, you don't need that `Obx` there. You can still access the controller without it.

Comment: I have a bottom sheet inside my scaffold and whenever the index of my bottomnavigation changes, the bottomsheet should close or open (doing that with a controller). I think i need the Obx for showing the right color of my bottomNavigationItem, right? (see my inital example)

Comment: Ok, you could even put your `showModalBottomSheet` in the Getx class and pass in `Get.context` and it will work the same. And yeah sorry you're correct about the Obx needed for selected item color if you're gonna be in a stateless widget.

Comment: I pun an obx variable inside a function (inside a Getx controller) and the function became reactive without using workers - is it possible? feels like something happand behind the scenes...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Obx you have to use Streams
first create a Controller

in this example i want to just listen to changes of a number

```
class AutoLoginCheck extends GetxController {
   var num= "0".obs;

void checkNum() {
    if (num.value == "1") {
      num.value = "0";
    } else {
      num.value = "1";
    }
  }
```

we can use this function to call that number changing

```
onTap: () {
   num.checkLoginVal();
                            },
```

Comment: I updated my question with my controller. I do not want to call a function inside my controller, but to call a local function of my screen with the bottomnavigationbar. In my previous project I used ProviderListener from Riverpod for this. But this time I want to use GetX.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a GetxController, you can listen to the value in the controller anywhere by adding `.obs` to the value you would like to listen to.

After adding .obs in the controller the method to listen is the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: Bro, please elaborate your answer with some sample codes so that all people who read your answer fully understand what you mean. Thank you